# Copy adjacent cell from offset row based on a dynamic value

Tags: excel, vba

I had posted something similar earlier, thought I had it, and deleted my post.  Ugh.  So, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- If the variables are equal c = d (comparing two loops), then locate the correct d value location (column/row) on the sheet
- Copy the d value from the cell into a specified range on another sheet .end(xlup).offset(1,0) ----this works fine
- Copy the adjacent cell value a few rows from the d value (offset 0,-16)

I can't get the offset value correctly.  It's giving me the range1 R3 value instead.

suggestions?

example:

```
Set range1 = wbk1.Worksheets(1).Range(R3:R20)
Set range2 = wbk2.worksheets(2).Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1,0)
Set range3 = wbk2.worksheets(2).Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1,0)
Set range4 = range1.Offset(0,-16)
For Each c in g.keys
     For Each d in range1 
          If c = d Then 
               range2.Value = d  
               range3.value = range4.value  (this isn't working)
          End If
     Next d
Next c
```

Final Code:

```
Set rngchassIP = wbkJackPot.Worksheets(1).Range("R3:R30") 
Set rngchassCS = wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("M2:M5")
Set rngchassyver = wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set rngchassypst = wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


For Each c In rngchassCS               
    For Each w In rngchassIP           
        If c = w Then                   
            rngchassyver.Value = w      
            rngchassypst.Value = w.Offset(0, -16)
        End If
    Next w
Next c
```

The root of the issue is that once the value/position of w is identified, I need to grab the offset(0,-16) from that cell and put that in "O".  I've tried a few different ways, but I'm just not seeing it... ugh.  Help please!

Comment: I'm confused, you refer to "A" and "B" in your question but have neither in your code. Is "A" the same as `c` and "B" the same as `d`? Also, what is `g`?

Comment: +1 to the above comment: the following piece of code `Set range1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("R1:R20")
Set range4 = range1.Offset(0, -16)
Set range3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
range3.Value = range4.Value
` works as expected, so please provide more relevant code sample.

Comment: Fixed the variables.  g.keys refers to a filesystemobject; suffice it to say that in the end the variables are equal. Peter states this works, so I'm digging further.  Will post again shortly.

Comment: Range4 is a multi-cell range and you're assigning it to one cell.  Try just assigning the value of d.offset(0,-16) instead

Comment: @Mike to be precise, I'll tried the above 4 lines of code on my workbook, and it is just copied the expected values to `range3` cell.

Comment: Id `g` really a filesystemobject, or is it a Dictionary object?

Comment: @Tim, sorry about that!  Dictionary object.   I'll post the actual code in a minute. it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing at what you're trying to do here....

```
Set range1 = wbk1.Worksheets(1).Range("R3:R20")

'are range 2 and 3 on the same row?
Set range2 = wbk2.worksheets(2).Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1,0)
Set range3 = wbk2.worksheets(2).Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1,0)

For Each c in g.keys
     For Each d in range1.Cells 
          If c = d Then 
               range2.Value = d  
               range3.value = d.Offset(0,-16)
               'What now?  Once one match has been found,
               '  any later matches will write to the same cells...
          End If
     Next d
Next c
```

Comment: That was exactly it.  I needed to do the offset of the d object. :)  Thanks Tim!!!!  Your post made me take a different look at it an I realized that I had actually tried that already, BUT I had the variables flip-flopped on the offset, so It wasn't working correctly.  Thanks again!